# Add multiple formula arguments

Tags: c#, jint

I have a Javascript formula saved in Database as a string and want to calculate it using [JINT](https://github.com/sebastienros/jint) in C#.

The formula has multiple variables and need to set them with their values.

```
int height = 10
int length = 10
int width = 5

string jsFormula = "height * length * width";
```

I need to set all 3 variables using `JINT` engine and get the output.

Answer (score 0):

You may do this in several ways.

Create Engine object,

```
var formulaEngine = new Engine();
```

Set variables one by one,

```
formulaEngine.SetValue("height", height);
formulaEngine.SetValue("width", width);
formulaEngine.SetValue("length", length);

double result = formulaEngine.Execute(jsFormula ).GetCompletionValue().AsNumber();
```

OR

```
double result= new Engine()
            .SetValue("height", height) 
            .SetValue("width", width)
            .SetValue("length", length)
            .Execute("x * x") 
            .GetCompletionValue() 
            .AsNumber();
```